# Is there a repeated measures aware version of the logrank test?

Tags: r, nonparametric, survival, logrank-test

I am looking for a repeated measures version of the [Logrank test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logrank_test).  If I am correct, I am looking for an equivalent of the Friedman test for survival data.

Any suggestions on where to look? (and R code will always be welcomed :) )

Thanks.

Comment: More information on the nature of the repetitions would be helpful. Perhaps clustered survival data methods including frailty models apply (and perhaps not).

Comment: There are n subjects, each one has k tasks timed.  I wish to compare the timing of the tasks between each other (are there timing different or not).  But they are dependent through the subject.  (Thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use a so-called marginal survival model. It would be more like Cox-regression than a log-rank test, i.e. proportional hazards for the effect of task would be assumed. It is implemented in the `survival` package:

```
mod <- coxph(Surv(time, censor) ~ task + cluster(id))
```

Here `task` would be a factor representing the task, and `id` would identify the subject. There is a book that goes into lots of detail on multivariate survival data: T.Therneau, P. Grambsch. *Modeling Survival Data: Extending the Cox Model*. Springer, 2000.